# Retrieving DOM nodes in repeating structures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am writing a library that builds up a complex HTML structure in given DIV container (using JQuery).

This is an example of how it works:

**HTML**

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

**LIBRARY JAVASCRIPT**

```
function complexStructure(container, opts) {
    this._container = $(container);
    // code handling options
    // ...
}

complexStructure.prototype = {
    show: function () {
        this._buildStructure();
    },

    _buildStructure: function () {
        // building html nodes here
        // ...
        for ( x=0; ... ) {
            for ( y=0; ... ) {
                // ...
                obj.attr("id", this._idOfElement(x, y));
                // ...
            }
        }
        // ...      
        this._container.empty().append(structure);
    },

    _idOfElement: function (x ,y) {
        return "element_x_" + x + "_y_" + y;
    },

    updateElementState: function (x, y, state) {
            var element = this._container.find("#" + this._idOfElement(x, y));
            // ...
            // update element
            // ...
    }
};
```

**LIBRARY USER JAVASCRIPT**

```
var a = new complexStructure(document.getElementById("a"), {... opts ...});
var b = new complexStructure(document.getElementById("b"), {... opts ...});
a.show();
b.show();
```

While building the nodes I assign them IDs so that I can retrieve them later.
To retrieve them I look for their ID starting from their ancestor DIV container since there could be more than one node with the same ID (in DIV *a* and DIV *b*).

I would like to know if it is ok to use duplicate IDs in cases like this or if I should prefer using a CSS class, or custom attributes.
What is the best practice in this case and what would you suggest me on the overall architecture?

Of course the actual code is more complex than this.

Thanks for your time

Comment: using dublicate ids is never "okay" :)

Comment: why don't you use the parent's ID as a seed for the child's ID? parentID + "_x_" + x + "_y_" + y;

Comment: @AdrianSalazar you mean choosing a random id for the container, such as "containerXXXX" where XXXX is a random number?

Comment: Yes this could do it, but you know that all your contaiers already have an ID? So you could access this._container.attr('id')

Comment: I could force the user to give the container an ID by changing the constructor: the first argument must be the container ID and not the container node. This way, anyway, would force the container to be somewhere in the DOM tree..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself.

To avoid ID duplicates you just need to append the ID of each node of the structure to the ID of their container.

One solution is to choose an ID for the container in the constructor or in a setup function:

```
this._containerId = ... generate random/unique/sequential ID ...;
```

and then append the ID of the elements to their container's ID:

```
_idOfElement: function (x, y) {
    return this._containerId + "_element_x_" + x + "_y_" + y;
}
```

If you are sure that the container passed to the constructor will always be inserted in the DOM tree (so that you can retrieve it with `getElementById`), another solution could be to change the structure constructor from:

```
function complexStructure(container, opts) {
    this._container = $(container);
    // code handling options
    // ...
}
```

to:

```
function complexStructure(containerId, opts) {
    this._containerId = containerId;
    this._container = $("#" + containerId);
    // code handling options
    // ...
}
```

and then use the same `_idOfElement` function of above.